# Download only artifacts I need in release pipeline and run tasks conditionnally

Tags: azure-devops

I have created a release pipeline that has multiple artifacts to be downloaded from multiple repositories.

Now, when I want to start the release I want to introduce a condition so that when the condition is met I download only the artifact I need and then run the task to deploy it otherwise when there is no condition all of the artifacts are downloaded thus all tasks are run.

How can I achieve that with azure DevOps ?
For conditions, I tried to look into
but for downloading only an artifact from multiple one I can't unless I specify a release pipeline for every project I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, build artifacts are downloaded to the agent. You can configure an option in the stage to skip the download of artifacts. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#artifact-sources---azure-pipelines

[image]

And use "Download Pipeline Artifact" task to specify your target Artifact. Set "Custom condition" within this task: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic

[image]

You can customize this behavior by forcing a stage to run by specifying a custom condition.